# Why can't I splice an array in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So, I have been trying to wrap my head around d3.js and cannot for the life of me figure out a way to splice an array. In the code below, i am importing a csv file (which has >30000 rows) and then trying to subset it to the first 40 values by splicing the array. While the command works in the console tab (i.e. data.splice(0,40)), it doesn't work within the script. What am i doing wrong?

```
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>
d3.csv("for_musp.csv", function(data2) {
  data = data2.map(function(d) { return +d["label"] ; });
});
var newData = data.splice(0,40);

};
</script>
```

Comment: where `data` declared?

Comment: data = data2.map(function(d) { return +d["label"] ; }); i am able to access the data variable in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (callback for `d3.csv` is asynchronous):

```
var newData;
d3.csv("for_musp.csv", function(data2) {
  data = data2.map(function(d) { return +d["label"] ; });
  newData = data.splice(0,40);
});
```

Comment: thanks! this works! however, what is asynchronous? any resource i can go through?

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#csv
it's documentation fo d3, for asynchronous javascript try here and then google: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Comment: in two words, code in callback will run not in order that it's written, but when file reading done, so all operations about data from file should be executed inside callback.

Comment: Thanks Ivan! makes sense. Hoewever, I now want to pop an element from the newData and add the next point from data to the newData array. This has to be iterated over a loop. What would be the best way to go about it.

Comment: depends on from which side of array you want to get it, google for `Array.pop()`, `Array.push()`,  `Array.shift()`,  `Array.unshift()`,